# scikit-learn Decision trees Regression: retrieve all samples for leaf (not mean)

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

I have started using scikit-learn Decision Trees and so far it is working out quite well but one thing I need to do   is retrieve the set of sample Y values for the leaf node, especially when running a prediction. That is given an input feature vector X, I want to know the set of corresponding Y values at the leaf node instead of just the regression value which is the mean (or median) of those values. Of course one would want the sample mean to have a small variance but I do want to extract the actual set of Y values and do some statistics/create a PDF. I have used code like this [how to extract the decision rules from scikit-learn decision-tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree) 
To print the decision tree but the output of the 'value'  is the single float representing the mean.  I have a large dataset so limit the leaf size to e.g. 100, I want to access those 100 values...

Comment: You need something like this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py

Comment: You can use `apply` to get the leaf ids of each sample; [see  here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299015/getting-the-distribution-of-values-at-the-leaf-node-for-a-decisiontreeregressor/38318135#38318135)

Comment: Thank you for these replies. I coded this up and get the same mean as shown when exporting the tree with graph_viz, so that's good. However although compact it doesn't seem efficient. Effectively I fit the data to a tree and each leaf node will end up with a sub-set of samples. I am then iterating through the data a second time to record which leaf node it falls into so i can get the corresponding target. But that data should already be stored in the leaf node somewhere? It doesn't seem slow so maybe not worth worrying about the duplication.

Comment: No, in the leaf, only means and counts are stored. I think, duplication is okay.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to use an (undocumented?) feature of the sklearn DecisionTreeRegressor object which is .tree.impurity
it returns the standard deviation of the values per each leaf

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.